# Can't write html dynamically in Jquery innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I use jquery to put html dynamically but it is not working... 
Here is what I have tried

```
$("#root").innerHtml("<h1>Hello</h1>")
```

Comment: Please read the jQuery docs. `innerHTML` is a JS method, in jquery it's [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html)

Comment: jQuery doesn't use `innerHTML`. Consider `$(...).html()` instead? `innerHTML` is a property not a function/

Comment: Oh okay.. Sorry

Comment: @Hskshe no need to apologise

Comment: If your question is already answered please post the solution as answer and accept it so that other people understand the problem ans its solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `innerHtml` instead use `html()`
You can do as below

```
$("#root").html("<div>Hello</div>")
```